# Are final goods commodities?

Tags: markets, commodities

I've been reading about final goods and commodities and some links

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_good

https://marketbusinessnews.com/financial-glossary/final-good/

mention that final goods are commodities. However, that is contradictory with commodities' property of substantial fungibility, which is "the market treats instances of the good as equivalent or nearly so with no regard to who produced them". What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you saying that your rosegold colored iPhone X with 256 GB storage is better than my rosegold colored iPhone X with 256 GB storage ?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't thinking like that. The wikipedia link states "A microwave oven or a bicycle is a final good", so if our smartphones are final goods, for example, they may be different because of different brands, e.g., yours is from Apple, mine is from Samsung.

Comment: Oil is a commodity, yet there are also variants of it? The same is true for precious metals, etc.

Comment: For me it's more understandable if you consider things such as petroleum, diamond, gold as commodities, because they are chemically the same. You can't say a diamond extracted from company A is worth more than that from company B. They are simply diamonds.

Comment: You are drawing arbitrary barriers. Obviously diamonds can be different if there is a difference in size/purity. Phones can also be different. No one is saying that all smartphones are fungible, in this regard producers matter. Smartphones with virtually identical capabilities are fungible or nearly fungible.

Comment: Think of a counter example: an original painting. It’s value is pretty much unique; not all Rembrandt paintings have the same value. Meanwhile, a store will sell identical smartphone models at the same price, even though there are lots of different models. However, this means that the “who produced them” part of the definition  is misleading. The problem is with that definition of commodity, as it is too narrow, and is only for things like grains and energy.

Comment: *commodity* is being used in two different senses.  The first is a broad meaning as a particular instance of goods and services.  The second is narrower for bulk goods for which a single price is commonly quoted